# 2800mhz RAM on a Asus Strix B350-F Gaming motherboard

Tags: memory, motherboard, desktop-computer

Hello i've been looking at its [QVL](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-B350-F-GAMING/HelpDesk_QVL/). However i can't find anything about Pinnacle ridge. The last entry was Raven Ridge.

Anyways, i don't know if the memory i bought is compatible with my motherboard (i didn't notice until after i got home that the one i bought was 2800mhz). On the specification on the motherboard there was no mention of a memory support @ 2800mhz.

This is my memory: [G-Skill Ripjaw 8GBx2](https://www.gskill.com/en/product/f4-2800c17d-16gvr)

This is my motherboard: [Asus Strix B350-F Gaming](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-B350-F-GAMING/overview/)

So, can my memory be supported with my motherboard?

Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: Go to http://www.crucial.com/. It will tell you what memory is compatible with your motherboard.

Comment: i already bought my memory, just wanted to know if i can still use this or not.

Comment: Go to the website. It will tell you if it will work or not.

Comment: can't choose memory other than crucial products

Comment: **It will work**. Maybe not @ 2800Mhz, you'll maybe have to tweak it in the bios (at least enable AMP/XMP profile), but it will work.